# An Efficient Route to Tate's Thesis

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I want to learn Tate's thesis. My advisor suggested the Book "Algebraic Number Theory" By Lang. However, it seems to be a long read before I reach Tate's Thesis. I want to know what are other good references to learn Tate's Thesis.

My background is a standard course in Algebra, some Commutative algebra and Galois Theory. However, I have not had any Algberaic Number Theory before.

In my search, I came across the book [Automorphic Forms](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-4435-9) by Anton Deitmar. They cover Tate's Thesis over rationals instead of arbitrary number fields. Is this a good way to learn Tate's Thesis or will I loose to much by considering only rationals? Also, this book discusses a lot of things in beginning which do not seem to be covered in Lang. So, I am a little skeptical about this book.

So finally, my question is how to understand Tate's thesis as quickly as possible with the above background?

Comment: Cassels-Frohlich is also a canonical reference for this sort of thing.

Comment: Just as a matter of principle, difficulty is conserved --- you'll probably have to put in roughly the same amount of work to understand Tate's thesis whether you read Lang or some other materials.

Comment: The book *An Introduction to the Langlands Program*,
 edited by J. Bernstein, D. Bump, S. S. Gelbart, has a chapter on Tate's thesis. I haven't read it though...

Comment: @anomaly I came across this book in my institute's library a couple of hours ago and will look at it.

Comment: @Neal Could you roughly sketch the things I would need to read to get to Tate's Thesis?

Comment: You should look at the masters thesis of one of Darmon's students which talks about Tate's thesis. EDIT: www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/theses/leahy/thesis.pdf